# How to customize the bootstrap form validation with vanilla javscript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I need to customize the bootstrap form validation according to my requirements. Here is the HTML of my form.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('sellingForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const contact = document.getElementById('contact');
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    if (isNaN(contact.value) || contact.value > 10) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
  form.classList.add('was-validated');
}, false)
```

```html
<form class="main-form bg-white needs-validation" novalidate action="submit-sell.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="sellingForm">
  <input name="ProductName" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Samsung mobile phone" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid title
  </div>
  <input name="contactNumber" type="tel" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="0777123456" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid contact no
  </div>
  <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid password
  </div>
  <input name="repeatPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="repeatPassword" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Passwords did not match
  </div>
  <select class="form-control" id="category" onchange="selectCategory(event)" name="category" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select a category</option>
    <option value="sell_vehicle">Sell Vehicle</option>
    <option value="computer">Computers</option>
    <option value="mobile">Mobile Phones</option>
    <!--Further options-->
  </select>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please select a category
  </div>
  <input required name="price" type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="120 000" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid price
  </div>
  <input required class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="negotiablity" id="negotiable" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label">Negotiable </label>
  <input required class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="negotiablity" id="not_negotiable" value="0">
  <label class="form-check-label">Not Negotiable</label>
  <textarea required name="description" rows="5" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder="Enter the product description here"></textarea>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid description
  </div>
  <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" id="file-input" required multiple name="picture">
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please select a valid image
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post Free Ad</button>
</form>
```

I have tried to customize the bootstrap JS code given in the documentation.

```
var form = document.getElementById('sellingForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const contact = document.getElementById('contact');
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    if (isNaN(contact.value) || contact.value > 10) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
  form.classList.add('was-validated');
}, false)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The form gets submitted without validating. I need help to validate following and then submit the form only if user input is valid.

1. User has filled all the required inputs.
2. The product name should not pass more than 25 characters and should not be less than 10 characters.
3. The contact number should not be a number and it should not be more or less than 10 numbers.
4. I should check whether the entered password and the repeated password are matching
5. I should check whether the chosen file is an image(in jpeg/png,etc formats) and whether a minimum of one and maximum of three images are inserted.
   These are the main solutions I require so I can apply in other areas.
   **No Jquery please** ..

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Your inputs have no constraints, meaning they aren't `required` or have a `pattern` attribute which check if the values are valid, like a telephone number. Without it  `form.checkValidity()` check will always be true.

Comment: @ChrisG Ok. I think I have modified the example to be minimal

Comment: just add event.preventDefault(); above the const contact declarartion @RifkyNiyas

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Ok. Ive added constraints and its working fine. How can I check for password and repeat password to be matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to check the passwords every time a user types in a new value in either of the fields.

Use the `input` event for this purpose. Get the values from both fields after while typing and check the validity of the fields by comparing the values. Also include your regex check on the first password for extra safety.

Store the results in global variables so that you can check if the passwords are valid in the `submit` function.

```js
let isPasswordMatch = false;
let isPasswordValid = false;
const passwordPattern = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}/;
const form = document.getElementById('sellingForm');

form.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const password = formData.get('password');
  const repeatPassword = formData.get('repeatPassword');

  // Validate the pattern again. 
  isPasswordValid = passwordPattern.test(password);

  // This will either be true or false based on if the values are the same or not.
  isPasswordMatch = repeatPassword !== '' && password === repeatPassword;
});

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // If either the form is invalid or the passwords don't match, stop!
  if (
    form.checkValidity() === false || 
    (isPasswordValid !== true && isPasswordMatch !== true)
  ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  form.classList.add('was-validated');
});
```

```html
<form id="sellingForm">
  <input name="password" type="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}" class="form-control" id="password" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid password
  </div>
  <input name="repeatPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="repeatPassword" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Passwords did not match
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it does not seem to work. I added a `pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}"` to the password to check for some security requirements of the password. Can you fix it please?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added your regex into it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your answer. It really helped me out. Before this edit I customized the simple version of code you gave as `repeatPassword.setAttribute('pattern', '['+value+']{'+value.length+'}'); ` and it worked. If possible include that too. Its more simple and effective